# как на canvas поставить цвет заливки между 2-мя линиями

Tags: javascript

чтобы между 2 линиями был какой нибудь цвет заливки

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("can");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(150,50);
context.lineTo(150,150);







context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(250,50);
context.lineTo(250,150);
context.stroke();
```

```css
width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это просто с помощью `context.fillRect`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("can");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "grey";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

```css
width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Если же вам нужны и линии, то прорисовывайте сначала квадрат, а потом линии:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("can");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(150, 50, 100, 100);
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(150,50);
context.lineTo(150,150);
context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(250,50);
context.lineTo(250,150);
context.stroke();
```

```css
width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Не забывайте с перемещением линий перемещать и квадрат!

Comment: а цвет боковых линий

Comment: @recile Готово.

Comment: это только таким способам делается?

Comment: @recile Есть еще [fill()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fill.asp)

Comment: а fill закрасит только если линии соединены?

Comment: @recile Да, только так.

Comment: ясно , спасибо !!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("can");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();

context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(150,50);
context.lineTo(150,150);

context.lineWidth=2;
context.moveTo(250,50);
context.lineTo(250,150);

context.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
  background-image:url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png);
  background-size:100px 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 150px 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Это нужно было сделать в js.

Comment: мне не фон а цвет фона надо установить и через js

Comment: @recile квадрат нарисовать что ли?

Comment: квадрат это просто, я думал чтобы между 2 линиями цвет, или как у квадрата убрать цвет линий по бакам